# COM object does not close

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a stock market software (AmiBroker) plugin wherein I have to call a COM object in order to retrieve the active symbols. I.e. when user requests for a particular symbol I have to send a Request to the server to fetch the stock data. So, AmiBroker has exposed some functions using COM which allows to retrieve the symbols that have been requested.

**Code**

```
System.Timers.Timer tm = new Timer(1000);
tm.Elapsed += delagate(sender, e)
{
    dynamic broker = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Broker.Application", true));
    hashtable.Add(uniquernd, broker.GetActiveSymbols());
    Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(broker);
}
```

Note: This is how I've implemented the logic in C# (Don't find syntactical errors in this code)

Sometimes when I close the AmiBroker application every COM object gets disposed successfully. But sometimes it does stay in process which causes malfunctioning. Is there any alternate way to achieve this by ensuring that the object will get disposed every time?

Comment: Is it possible that the code inside the delegate takes longer then 1 second?

Comment: Are you also releasing the symbols you got back wich should also be COM objects?

Comment: no i am doing exactly what i have written in the code sample

Comment: If it's like Excel's COM model, you should assign `broker.GetActiveSymbols()` in a variable, and then release this variable (after use).  Sometimes, references are kept without any reason if you don't do that.

Comment: actually i am returning a List<string> which contains list of active symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM objects in C# need special handling.

You should use a variable to hold the pointer to each COM object, which means that if your object has a property that returns another COM object, you should use variables to keep them, and then use `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(v);` on each.
Otherwise, the .NET framework will create an ah-hoc COM holder object, that will be freed some time in the future.

In your `finally` clause, remember to set the variable to **null**, so that the Garbage Collector will free it completely.

You can also call `GC.Collect();` to force it to collect garbage right now.

Comment: I am not sure but sometimes it fails to close the COM Object because i am using COM object inside a timer

Comment: @Tuscan what is the return type of `GetActiveSymbols()` ?

Comment: It returns a List<string>

Comment: But List<string> is a Dot.Net class, and can not be returned from a COM object... Are you talking about some kind of a string collection maybe?

Comment: Actually it returns a string i.e. Symbol Name code: for(i=0;i<=broker.Documents.Count-1;i++){ string name = broker.Documents[i].Name; }

Comment: Can you post the code for this method here? I want to make sure no other Com objects involved here. If you omit the line completly and add an empty string instead of calling this method, does the object get released?

Answer (score 0):

The `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` method will loop through all the references to the COM object provided and remove them. You might try that instead of ReleaseComObject().

Comment: Yes i have already tried with Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject but didn't help